# How to store a Display text along with Hyperlink in Microsoft access 2010 database?

Tags: microsoft-access-2010, microsoft-access-2013

i mean how to store "Display text along with Hyperlink" in microsoft access database

so that when you generate "Forms" from the database table.

and you click on the that item text , you are actually transferred to the website.

and what type of field and Format it will require for this to be.

Hyperlink data type field only stores , hyperlink and not display text, can't find a

"Format" how to attain so.

Comment: You're probably going to need to write some code that displays the text you want on your form (from your db table) but when the text is clicked it reads the URL from the next field in your table and opens your browser to the URL...

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the "Parts of a hyperlink address" section of the Microsoft document

[About hyperlinks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/about-hyperlinks-HP005188817.aspx)

> A hyperlink address can have up to four parts that are separated by the number sign (#):
>
> displaytext#address#subaddress#screentip

So, a Hyperlink field in Access could contain

```
Super User#http://superuser.com##A question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.
```

The field would display as "Super User", clicking on it would take you to http://superuser.com, and when the mouse pointer hovers over the field the ScreenTip would display "A question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users."